# NetworkX - draw_networkx() plot all the nodes on top of each other

Tags: python, networkx

I have tried to plot network data with networkX but the run into some trouble. Below is a dummy example. The code runs and plots the data but all the nodes are stacked on top of each other. Have not found a solution at Stacked.

Note that the plot works for nx.DiGraph() but not for nx.Graph()...

I have tried a range of things including shifting between draw() and draw_networkx()

Can it be a dependency issue relating to Matplotlib?

---

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node("Singapore")
G.add_node("San Francisco")
G.add_node("Tokyo")
G.add_nodes_from(["Riga", "Copenhagen"])
G.add_edge("Singapore","San Francisco")
G.add_edge("San Francisco","Tokyo")
G.add_edges_from(
[
    ("Riga","Copenhagen"),
    ("Copenhagen","Singapore"),
    ("Singapore","Tokyo"),
    ("Riga","San Francisco"),
    ("San Francisco","Singapore"),
]
)

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

---

Comment: I've just run your code (I had to add plt.show() at the end) and it gave me a nice graph. So probably the code itself is not a problem.

For clarity I added the line at the beginning:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

and this one at the end:
    plt.show()

Comment: Thanks @MarcinCuprjak. I'm still unable to get an accurate plot. It is strange since the directed graph works as expected. Im starting to wonder if it is a package dependency issue. What version of matplotlib and networkx are you running? I have 3.6.3 for matplotlib and 2.6.3 for networkx. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have matplotlib==3.6.2 and networkx==2.8.8

Comment: What happens if you set the the figure size explicitly? `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10)); nx.draw_networkx(G, ax=ax)`? Also, an image would be helpful. Since you have low rep, you will have to upload it to imgur or an equivalent and then link the image.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBrodersen, but the fig size did not change the outcome. However, I found a suggestion to alter the matplotlib version to 3.4.3 and that did it! So now it's up and running. Thanks for your help and suggestions.